# In what areas is kindergarten most effective developmentally?

Tags: reference-request, developmental-psychology, educational-psychology

I expect that state-funded kindergarten and pre-kindergarten would be most effective in areas where there is no state-funded day-care. Additionally, I would expect it to be most beneficial to the demographics that cannot afford alternative child-care. However, I can't find any literature reviews that compare across various systems and countries, although I did find [this review that focuses on the US](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0749379702006554). Are there more modern international studies available?

Comment: A kindergarten, as I undertand it, is not by definition not funded by the state. So are you asking about state-funded versus privately funded kindergartens? Or about kindergarten versus kids staying home with a parent? Or about different educational methods in different kindergartens? Or about what? Please clarify!

Comment: @what I meant state-funded. I wasn't aware there was none state-funded kindergarten.

Comment: @what There is state-funded kindergarten (i.e., public school) in the US--what country are you speaking from?

Comment: Some child day care in the US is funded by churches and other for-profit organizations. These are (sometimes?) accredited by the state, but they are not necessarily state-funded.

Comment: @Seanny123 You didn't explain what your question is about. Is it about day care versus parental care? Schooling toddlers versus letting them play? (Both can happen at home or in kindergartens.) Please explain.

Comment: Due to my lack of knowledge in the area, I assumed that the variations between kindergartens were minimal. I was hoping for a review that would examine where kindergartens were most effective and why. Whether this be because of a lack of alternatives to childcare or because of the excellence of the kindergarten program.